# Boot from a windows 7 harddrive on a linux first laptop?

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, boot

I have a windows 7 hardrive from my old laptop that died. I use Ubuntu exclusively on my new computer so I never had a need to dual boot.

Now, there's some info on the old drive that I want to access. I first tried a straight switch of the harddrives. The windows drive wasn't recognized, and so I felt silly as I realized grub wouldn't work with the windows drive.

Is there any way to boot my windows 7 drive on my linux first laptop?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can, because Windows uses hardware information to enforce single-user licensing. Two alternatives:

1. Put the HDD in the laptop.

   Boot from a USB device (Ubuntu or WindowsPE) that is writeable and large enough to hold your data.

   Copy data from HDD to USB.

   Reinsert the laptop's HDD.

   Reboot and copy data from USB to HDD.
2. Get an external USB adapter for the HDD. Some are less than US$10, such as [http://www.amazon.com/Drive-Adapter-Converter-Optical-External/dp/B002OV1VJW](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002OV1VJW) or http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=8898138&CatId=3770. You can get your data back and can continue using it for additional storage.

Comment: Yea I was considering something along those lines. The trouble is I have a bitcoin wallet on there. Not sure if I can access the wallet without booting into windows. I'll be giving a try anyways. Thanks.